# I want to know about the motion of a current carrying wire in external magnetic field

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, electromagnetism, electric-current, conductors

Suppose a straight current carring wire of finite length if kept in a external magnetic field (perpendicular to its length say dot). I know initially it would experience a magnetic force of magnitude ILB due to drift velocity of charges inside wire but now  the wire would gain velocity , but if I use lorentz law to find magnetic force again what way the wire be doing motion.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose current through the wire is in the x direction (free electron velocity in the –x direction) and the magnetic field is in the y direction. Then, for a right-handed co-ordinate system, the magnetic force is in the z direction.

If we neglect other forces, the wire will acquire an increasing velocity in the z direction. So the free electrons in the wire now have components of velocity in both the –x and the z directions. The first of these continues to give the force in the z direction. The second of these gives a force $(-e)(\vec {v_z} \times \vec B)$, that is in the x direction, on the free electrons. This opposes their motion along the wire, in other words it gives rise to the back-emf predicted by Lenz's law.